# High CPU utilization due to cron job which were running scripts under /tmp/.jenkins/jenkins/ directory

Tags: jenkins

/tmp/.jenkins/jenkins/ directory has 2 scripting files. Please find the scripts below:

```
File Name: j 
if test -r /tmp/.jenkins/jenkins/j.pid; then
    pid=$(cat /tmp/.jenkins/jenkins/j.pid)
    if $(kill -CHLD $pid >/dev/null 2>&1)
    then
        exit 0
    fi
fi
cd /tmp/.jenkins/jenkins
touch j.pid
chmod u+x j.pid
./run &>/dev/null
```

```
File Name: run
./jenkins & echo $(( $! + 1 )) > j.pid 2> /dev/null
```

These scripts were running as a cron job at every second which is resulting in high CPU utilization of the server. It is reaching upto `90%`. When we comment out this scripts from cron job, the CPU utilization went down to `15%`.

Can someone help me to understand the purpose of this scripts and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: We too started getting this a couple days ago.  First thought was our server was compromised and used for mining.  Is there a vulnerability in Jenkins?

Comment: are you using Jenkins on public subnet?
if yes then you shouldn't.